# How to add a period to all files starting with a certain pattern in terminal?

Tags: linux, filenames, rename

I have several files all starting with the name

```
template_file
template_images
```

I want to make these files hidden by adding a period before all of them. What is the terminal command line I can use to add a period with all files starting with template as its filename so now they are all ex.

```
.template_file 
.template_images
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
rename -n 's/^template/.$&/' template*
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl rename` executable.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>